# Is createResponse supported in Mono's System.Net.Http?

Tags: f#, mono, visual-studio-code, azure-functions, ionide

I'm editing F# Azure Function files using VS Code and Ionide on a Mac.

Below is my little test function:

```
#if !COMPILED
#I "../packages/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs/lib/net45/"
#r "Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.dll"
#endif

#r "System.Net.Http"
#r "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage"
#r "Newtonsoft.Json"

open System
open System.Net
open System.Net.Http
open Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host

type Item = { id: string; comment: string }

let Run(req: HttpRequestMessage, output: byref<Item>, log: TraceWriter) =
    let item = { id = "Some ID"; comment = "test comment" }
    output <- item 
    async {
        // createResponse has a red line beneath it
        return req.createResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created)
    } |> Async.StartAsTask
```

When viewieng this file in VS Code, there is a red line beneath `createResponse`.

When I put my mouse over `createResponse`, the error message is `The field, constructor or member 'createResponse' is not defined.`. Is this because Mono's version of `System.Net.Http` doesn't support `createResponse`?

Given that I don't want to run or compile this file locally, is there anyway to tell Ionide to use a different version of `System.Net.Http`?

Comment: It's `CreateResponse`, not `createResponse`. Wrong capitalization.

Comment: Just tried `CreateResponse` but still get the same error message. Furthermore, in all the Azure Function examples in F#, it is using the lowercase version. In other words, using `createResponse`, the function compiles and runs without any issues on Azure Functions.

Comment: [Here is an example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook#http-trigger-sample-in-c) that I found just now. It uses PascalCase. Can you point me to examples using camelCase? Are you sure the file `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.dll` exists in that location? Have you tried to send this script to F# interactive line by line?

Comment: The examples aren't available publically - it's only accessible once you login to the Azure portal, create a new function and then choose to build a function from a template.

Yes, `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.dll` exists. When I spell it incorrectly, I get a red line under `TraceWriter`.

I haven't tried to send this interactively. I'm new to F# and assumed that running an Azure function locally would be pointless.

Lastly, it seems that an alternative way of achieving the same result is to use `return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)`.

Answer (score 0):

The [CreateResponse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httprequestmessageextensions.createresponse(v=vs.118).aspx) method is an extension method - although it exists in the `System.Net.Http` namespace it lives in a different assembly. (I'm not sure why it compiles in Azure, maybe some additional references are added by default?)

To make Ionide happy I added these nuget packages:

- [System.Net.Http.Formatting.Extension](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Net.Http.Formatting.Extension/)
- [Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core/)

And these references:

```
#I ".."
#r "packages/System.Net.Http.Formatting.Extension/lib/System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll"
#r "packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core/lib/net45/System.Web.Http.dll"
```